# Walking (tic-toc) clock with js and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, time, clock

Have a script with "walkin" clock on javascript and php (i need server-side time - it's important), but it's stop and don't count until refresh a page. What i'm doing wrong, please help. Thank you.

```
<?php $Hour = date("H");
$Minute = date("i");
$Second = date("s");
$Day = date("d");
$Month = date("m"); ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
function clock() {
var d = new Date();
var month_num = d.getMonth();
var day = d.getDate();
var hours = <?php echo $Hour;?>;
var minutes = <?php echo $Minute;?>;
var seconds = <?php echo $Second?>;

month=new Array("января", "февраля", "марта", "апреля", "мая", "июня", "июля", "августа", "сентября", "октября", "ноября", "декабря");

if (day <= 9) day = "0" + day;
if (hours <= 9) hours = "0" + hours;
if (minutes <= 9) minutes = "0" + minutes;
if (seconds <= 9) seconds = "0" + seconds;

date_time = "Today - " + day + " " + month[month_num] + " " + d.getFullYear() + " y. &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Now - "+ hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;

if (document.layers) {
 document.layers.doc_time.document.write(date_time);
 document.layers.doc_time.document.close();
} else document.getElementById("doc_time").innerHTML = date_time;
 setTimeout("clock()", 1000);}
</script>

<span id="doc_time">Date & time</span>

<script type="text/javascript">clock();</script>
```

Comment: What is `document.layers`? It's some element ID?

Comment: Also, why do you use `var d = new Date(); var month_num = d.getMonth();` if you have it already defined in PHP? Same for `var day = d.getDate();`. Why would you want to mix JS and PHP

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan... yes there is ID Element.. I see a mistake.

Comment: Don't target DOM elements (ID) by using `window.layers` As soon someone, or yourself, introduce a global `var layers = "foo"` you'll lose control over your element. Use `document.getElementById("layers")` instead; or the unnoticeably slower `document.querySelector("#layers")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Your issue:**

- PHP serves on page request the respective date values.
- You store those values into JS
- You loop all over again the same values. Therefore the loop works but the values are unchanged.

**Instead what you should:**

- Create a `var D = new Date("<?php echo date('D M d Y H:i:s O');?>");`
  **outside of your function**.
- On every timeout, add one second to your initial PHP Date
  `DATE = PHP:initial + JS:now - JS:initial`

```js
function zero(n) { return n > 9 ? n : "0" + n; }
var months = [
  "января", "февраля", "марта", "апреля", "мая", "июня",
  "июля", "августа", "сентября", "октября", "ноября", "декабря",
];
var jsDate = new Date(); // Store JS time

// I'll hardcode a date string for demo purpose:
var phpDate = new Date("Sun Sep 09 2018 23:59:55 +0000");
// You, use this instead:
// var phpDate = new Date("<?php echo date('D M d Y H:i:s O');?>");

function clock() {
  var diff = +new Date() - +jsDate;     // Get seconds difference
  var date = new Date(+phpDate + diff); // Add difference to initial PHP time

  var y = date.getFullYear(),
    M = date.getMonth(),
    d = zero(date.getDate()),
    h = zero(date.getHours()),
    m = zero(date.getMinutes()),
    s = zero(date.getSeconds());

  document.getElementById("doc_time").innerHTML = `
    Дата: ${d} ${months[M]} ${y}. &emsp;
    Время: ${h}:${m}:${s}
  `;

  setTimeout(clock, 1000);
}

clock();
```

```html
<div id="doc_time"></div>
```

Comment: @ВикторияСикрет PS, edited a bit the code to make it a bit more precise. By blindly adding 1 second using `setSeconds` after a period of time the clock would lose accuracy since a timeOut of 1000 is not guaranteed to be exactly 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

The php code runs once on page load so hour, minute and seconds will always remain same in each call of clock() function.

If you really need to do such a thing, you have to use AJAX to request a php script each second to get current time from server but remember these requests will have delay and also can put a huge load on server if multiple users open the page at the same time.

Comment: sorry but page reload it's not my way... but thank you for your time

Comment: @ВикторияСикрет AJAX will **not** cause a page refresh. Google for AJAX to get an idea what it does.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan... ok thank you very much for your time